# CSS float: right; not working

Tags: html, css, css-float

```html
<div id="left-aligh">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Registered With</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
        <li style="float: right;"><a class="active" href="#">Regsiter</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

All the menu items have been pushed to left using this code below

```css
#left-aligh {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 300px;
}
```

but I want to push the register alone to the right for the float option is not working. I have tried to declare inside `<li>` itself but it's not working, kindly help.

Comment: Seems to float right based on what you've posted: https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/79hxaqb0/

Comment: Post the code that you tried and doesn't work !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @vals  check this fiddle please? https://jsfiddle.net/Xbow23/uw91kdks/

Comment: add width:500px to the ul

Comment: Why #page-wrap-header have width of 2080px? Is it intentional?

Comment: @vals the code `width:500px` worked but the question is why `style="float: right;"`  didnt work?

Comment: @demonofthemist nothing intentional, do you think that would have affected the alignment? of `register`

Comment: It works. It's just that the ul doesn't have space left to the right, so it doesn't show

Comment: @GladwinJames Added an answer below, please check if it helps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your use `float:right;` on an element, it moves to right of the parent, NOT to the right of page. In above case it indeed moved to the right of parent, it looked like it didn't worked as expected cause parent, i.e `UL` element has that much width only.

Note that by default `UL` is not a *block level element*, thus it wont span over entire available lenght but exapand according to it's children, also you used float left on parent of `UL`, which cause it to float to left, floated elements, whether block level or not, do not occupy entire length, instead exand as per its children same an `inline-block elements`!

Remove float from wrapper `div` & make `UL` *block level*, then your `float:right` will work as expected!

As follow:

HTML

```
<div id="left-align">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Registered With</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><a class="active" href="#">Regsiter</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left-align {
    /* Remove float */
    position: relative;
    bottom: 300px;
}

ul {
    display:block;
    padding:0;
}

#page-wrap-header {
     /* removed width */
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: left;
}
```

Due to width on #page-wrap-header it was going outside window bounds, thus I removed it. you can tweak it later as per your need.

See DEMO : [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uw91kdks/5/)

Comment: thanks for the explanation understood clearly.have to learn more

Comment: Thank you for your understandable answer. It's really helpful for me. I use the Foundation CSS framework with .float-right class but I have no clue the reason causing this issue. It worked in the past.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="left-aligh">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Registered With</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Regsiter</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#left-aligh {
    position: relative;
}

li:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

I am not sure if it's okay but it works for me. :)